# document.getElementById.click() creates loop

Tags: javascript, php

I want to trigger a PHP script to run once the page is fully loaded while making sure it runs only once by checking if a session already exists or not. The problem I'm running into is that my script is creating a loop and page goes into reload frenzy.

I think shell exec triggers a refresh when the script finishes, which I need to keep because it sets some sessions which will trigger some divs to be hidden/shown after the reload.

Everything works if I click the button myself. How can I make the PHP trigger only once on page load based on the sessions values?

The reason I'm window.addEventListener is because the user will access this page based on a button on a previous page. But that causes the php to trigger first when the user clicks the button and only loads the page the button refers to after the script has finished.

Button

```
<form method="post">
    <button id="CheckConnectionBtn" name="CheckConnectionBtn" class="CheckConnectionBtn" button>Start </button>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['CheckConnectionBtn'])) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['SEND_TRIGGER'])) {
        $_SESSION["SEND_TRIGGER"] = "SET";
        $output = shell_exec("/var/www/html/scripts/ping.sh");
        $_SESSION["CONNECTION_CHECK"] = "$output";
    } else {
        echo "Do nothing";
    }
}
?>
```

Script

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  document.getElementById("CheckConnectionBtn").click();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your script need to be wrapper in `php` condition.

Comment: "that causes the php to trigger first when the user clicks the button and only loads the page the button refers to after the script has finished"...yes that's how the web works. So maybe the best idea is to just run your PHP code when the page loads. Then set a session value, so that any other requests to the same script won't run that block of code. `if (!isset($_SESSION['SEND_TRIGGER'])) {` should be sufficient for that (as long as you've written `session_start();` somewhere before that in the PHP).

Comment: "I think shell exec triggers a refresh when the script finishes"... no I don't believe so. Anyway PHP can't refresh your browser! It's on your server. All it can do is return a response to the browser. Posting a form back (which is the result of clicking your button) is what causes a refresh.

Comment: @ADyson I tried that but then the PHP executes as soon as the button on the previous page is clicked and calls the page with the PHP script. All this happens BEFORE the page is loaded. From a user pov it looks like the page is hanging. My script can take several minutes to complete which is why I want to execute it only AFTER the page has loaded.

Comment: Ok. Sounds like you need AJAX then